# VBA error 13 : Type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA.

I am trying to extract all columns from other file but the result is displayed with error 13. How can I solve it?

```
Sub generate_data()

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets("Output").Activate
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
        "ODBC;DSN=HKGHKGT_UBET;Description=HKGHKGT_UBET;UID=SiuH;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2016;WSID=HKHKDNO304NB;DATABASE=" _
        ), Array("UBet")), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        'CommandType = 0
        .CommandText = Array("select * from UBet..cathy_fin where duns_no in(" & Sheets("Main").Range("A2").Value & ") order by stmt_date desc")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "HKGHKGT_UBET"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("HKGHKGT_UBET").TableStyle = ""
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the error occur in a specific row?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy Yes it did. It is fully functional with 10 data that I input like this ( 123, 123, 123, 123). But the error appear when I type 11 data or above.

Comment: It's currently unclear where you input any data. Please post a complete example.